# different hardware - different solutions despite of one topic like e.g. nvidia

Tags: discussion

e.g. with this nvidia-post I got voted up or voted down, because this solution only works for CUDA optimus cards of nvidia - when bumblebee is added as repo.
( https://askubuntu.com/questions/297030/nvidia-frickle-with-hybrid-chipset-is-now-over-finally )

So here it is not correct then - to be voted down several times by others, who did not succeed with this solution ( one or two did succeed ). Yes, I got voted down too, because this was not posted as question, instead posted like a blog. I only want to say, that it is sometimes tricky to post the correct solution as anwer for one topic, when several users don't know how to handle this solution, and then are voting somebody down, when they have "somehow no luck" with an answer.

- in future I will pay attention more to post more "compact" answers to avoid being mis-rated.
- there should be an option too in board of askubuntu, to mark a question/solution with being dependent on certain hardware - resp. marked with a hint, that one has to take care of it, because it is somehow case-sensitive like with nvidia ?!

Comment: I'm sure there is a question somewhere in this ... can you highlight it please? :)

Comment: @fossfreedom sorry - I did something wrong - wanted to post this on the "discussion"-page :) - so will soon re-edit it a bit. Not now. Need a break here.

Answer (score 4):

This just seems to be confusion on how the site works. The site doesn't work by posting a post like this. People weren't downvoting because your content was wrong, it was being downvoted because it was posted wrong, which I don't agree with, but whatever. This is a very detailed answer so we should save it! What I recommend is reposting this like this:

1. Post a new question with a more descriptive title, something like "How do I get an NVIDIA Optimus card with CUDA working?" or something. "nvidia-frickle with hybrid chipset is now over finally?" doesn't really tell me what the question is about.
2. In the body of the question pretend you're on jeopardy, list the model number of your card, and perhaps link to the Nvidia question for people without Optimus/CUDA as reference (so that the other question gets a backlink).
3. Then after you have posted a question post the rest of your post as an answer, and then accept it.
4. Rejoice as users reward you with votes for self documenting a problem!

If you get lost with the Q+A style of post, just toss it up there as best as you can and link it here, then the community can go in and help you fix it up. As far as the system marking a solution that only works with certain hardware, put that in the title! So "How do I fix foo on bar?" becomes "How do I fix foo on a Bar 2000GTS?"